# Return to "my app" when navigation finish

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2

In `Android`, using `Google Maps API v2 Intent`, is it possible return to `my app` after the user arrives at his destination using navigation?

Thanks!

Comment: No it is not possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure why you would want to do that. But one possible solution could be:

1. Get location updates in background using some `Service`.
2. Use `GeoFencing`.
3. As soon as you detect you are at your destination using GeoFencing, either a) You launch your `Activity` from the `Service` (which is not a good UX at all as the user will be disrupted from his Maps experience), or b) You show a notification to the user and user can launch your app from that.

Beware that starting Android O, [the frequency of location updates you get while on background is very limited](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background-location-limits.html). One possible solution would be to know how long it will take the user to reach the destination and plan your location updates accordingly.

Comment: I started use this solution, but ask about other ways to make more "beauty" experience... I need this feature because, in my app, I have a map with some "places" available for user navigate to, but I don't need turn-by-turn navigation IN my app, just "place" selection, but when user arrive, I need my app "re open" and offer some options for user...

Comment: I would personally prefer a Notification for a nice user experience when they arrive at the location. It doesn't disrupt the existing UX (navigating in Maps) by suddenly changing the app, yet they can know that they have some options waiting in your app.
The notification can include what can the user do after they reach their location using your app, that might take their attention and make them launch your app from the notification.